# Why there is nonconstant linear funectional $\Gamma $ on $X$ such that $\Gamma (A) \cap \Gamma (B)$ contains at most one point?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $X$ is a real vector space(without topology). call a point $x \in A \subset X$ an internal point of $A$ if $A-x$ is an absorbing set.Suppose $A$ and $B$ are disjoint convex set in $X$ and $A$ has an internal point.Why there is nonconstant linear funectional $\Gamma $ on $X$ such that $\Gamma (A) \cap \Gamma (B)$ contains at most one point ?

Comment: Can you apply some form of the Hahn-Banach theorem to this?  In general, to separate sets $A,B$ you should separate $A-B$ from $\{0\}$.